# Update EC2 AMI root drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 AMI that I create instances from to be used to execute builds. I now need to modify this AMI because I need an additional program installed on it. What I want to do is make my AMI point at a different snapshot to use as its root drive (a snapshot with the new program installed) and things would be all well and good. But, I can't find a way to do this. Someone from Amazon on the forums said it's not possible, but I'm not so sure. So, I wanted to ask here.

I know I can just take the updated snapshot I want and create an entirely new AMI from it, but this results in a new AMI ID and now I need to go change the AMI ID which my scripts use to launch a new instance. I don't want to do this every time I realize I need a change to my AMI setup.

Comment: I'm not an expert or anything, but isn't an AMI essentially an image of an instance's root drive? If that's the case, it doesn't make sense for an AMI to 'point to' a snapshot to use as its root drive; a new instance created from the AMI will be allocated a new volume to be used as its root. If I'm right, then the only solution is to save a new AMI from a running instance with the new program.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down that way; I think you're right.

Comment: You probably figured it out yourself, @gfree, but you may want to put the AMI ID your scripts use - outside of said scripts (e.g., in the environment) so there will be only one place you'd need to change when you go with a new AMI. Sorry if I stated the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you can build private AMI from exist ec2 instance (of course you can public it as well). Then you can start a new ec2 instance from "My AMI" with all installed application/package directly.

Take a look on this doc

[Amazon Machine Images (AMI)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)

There are new feature such as `Docker` introduced by AWS last month, but it is not ready to public to use currently.

Another benefit to create private AMI image is, it will save you much time when you need launch a new instance.

If you need update your configuration file, after new AMI created, I recommend to make a CI trigger (via Jenkins, for example). run a awscli command in script, it will easily update your config file. All these tasks, include create a new AMI, update configuration file, etc can be done under Jenkins/bamboo automatically.

***If you are not confident with this way***, then think about  `cloudformation` template. it will make big improvement in your system. But if you fully set it, the cloudformation way will save you a lot of time in future changes.

In Cloudformation, you need set launch configuration and its autoscaling group, you still need create private AMI image, but every time after create new image, you need trigger a script to update the ami image in its Launch configuration, after that, any new instance will automatically use the new AMI.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But, that results in a new AMI ID which is specifically what I don't want because then I have to update my code or a configuration file. If I can launch by "Alias" or something, instead of AMI ID, that would be fine, too.